integrate messenger chat box to my own website
i want to integrate messenger chat box in my website how can i achieve this ?
"On May 9, 2024, you will no longer be able to access any of the functionality of the Chat Plugin. Effective immediately, Chat Plugin in guest mode is no longer available. Other features like m.me links will still be available for you to use." - I have already seen this message, so for now it isn't possible to integrate messenger chat box to my own website anymore?
